# CSS prefixes to achieve cross browser gradient 

Tags: css

I'm hoping to achieve a cross browser gradient, if you inspect the anchor at the top right corner running inline with the branding of my mobile site it has been styled with the prefix moz for Firefox:

[www.test-bed.co.uk/mobile/](http://www.test-bed.co.uk/mobile/)

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #4A4A4A, #2C2C2C) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

May I ask is there is a similar way to achieve a cross browser gradient solution with the IE, Opera and webkit prefixes?

Comment: Depending by your needs you should also take a look at [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) and at [prefix-free](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/)

Answer (score 2):

An online tool that automates CSS gradient rule generation for all modern browsers: [little link](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

But generically, here's the main syntax:

```
background: #color; /*fallback*/
background: -moz-linear-gradient(...);/*Firefox*/
background: -webkit-gradient(...);/*Chrome + Safari*/
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(...);/*Another Chrome + Safari*/
background: -o-linear-gradient(...); /*Opera*/
background: -ms-linear-gradient(...); /*IE10+*/
background: linear-gradient(...); /*W3C standards*/
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#color', endColorstr='#color',GradientType=0); /*IE6-9*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CSS3 Please](http://css3please.com/). I personally like their indentation style.

```
.box-gradient {
  background-color: #444444;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#444444), to(#999999)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Chrome 10+, Safari 5.1+, iOS 5+ */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Firefox 3.6-15 */
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #444444, #999999); /* Opera 11.10-12.00 */
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, #444444, #999999); /* Firefox 16+, IE10, Opera 12.50+ */
}
```

As you can see, there is no `-ms-` prefix needed since [IE10 supports the W3C syntax](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/06/25/unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-ie10.aspx) right away. Please make sure that you use the [correct W3C syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-images-20120417/#linear-gradients) for `linear-gradient()`!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firefox as a browser. then you may want to use the addon called colorzilla. It is a nice tool that comes with options like Color picker, Eye Dropper, Pallette browser, **CSS gradient generator**, web page DOM code Analyzer , inspect Last element as well as zoom.

However you can generator css gradient'sat the folllowing link:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/